# How to add event on control created during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, events

I want to create click event on buttons, (2 Buttons are creating during runtime)

I am using this to create buttons:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        Button Btn = new Button();
        Btn.Name = "btn" + k;
        Btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (k *110), 60 + (20 * j) * 2);
        Btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 30);
         if (k == 0)               
            Btn.Text = "Back";

         else
            Btn.Text = "Calculate";

        this.Controls.Add(Btn);
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhance your loop like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
{
    Button Btn = new Button();
    Btn.Name = "btn" + k;
    Btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + (k *110), 60 + (20 * j) * 2);
    Btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 30);
     if (k == 0)               
        Btn.Text = "Back";

     else
        Btn.Text = "Calculate";

    Btn.Click += button_Click; // <-- This is where it happens!

    this.Controls.Add(Btn);
}
```

Then add the event handler:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn.Name.Equals("..."))
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }    
}
```

Please note that within the event handler you need to decide which button has been pressed by looking at the `Name` property.

Comment: That's What I want :)
Thanks

Comment: No problem ;-) By the way, the equivalent of "That's what I want" is to mark my answer as accepted :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
Btn.Click += button1_Click;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: it says 
`The name'Btn' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @UzairAli It should be inside the for loop. right before the `this.Controls.Add(Btn);` line

Comment: Its working But problem is that both buttons use same event (Back and Calculate)

Comment: @UzairAli See my answer, I show how to distinguish both buttons.

Comment: @UzairAli either do what he said and check for the buttons name, or you need to have a new method for each button which means you can use a dynamic for

Comment: Dynamic for?
never heard of it
I am Beginner

Comment: @UzairAli for in itself is "dynamic" because you control the number of iterations in run time. If you only ever want 2 buttons, you shouldn't use a for, you should just create 2 different buttons and add them.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create 2 buttons during runtime using dynamic for ?

Comment: @UzairAli that's exactly what you did. without a for loop you would need to first create a back button and then a calculate button. You want me to paste that code in my answer?

Comment: Ok now i understand what you want to tell me but that will increase my code size
sorry for bad english

Comment: @UzairAli you can make a method and reuse it to create buttons. but increasing the code is not a bad thing, repeating yourself for no reason is a bad thing.

Comment: Well your idea is not bad
Maybe some time i will use that :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
   btn1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn1_Click);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Btn.Click += Btn_Click;

void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

in VS you can type `Btn.Click +=` the press tab twice and it will generate the method for you.